# Error when modifying namespace for nginx ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I was trying to modify my ingress as my ingress controller and ingress service are runnign in nginx-ingress name space.

I tried to to use: `kubectl edit ing lhingress` where ingress name is lhingress. It opens up an editor but whne i try to modify and then save it. i get below error.

```
error: the namespace from the provided object "nginx-ingress" does not match the namespace "default". You must pass '--namespace=nginx-ingress' to perform this operation.
```

Could you please suggest me how to point this ingress to different namespace

Comment: how are you trying to save the file back, are you using the kubectl apply command?

Comment: namespace can't be changed

Comment: @Ogbe it opens up an editor so we can save it like we do with an vi editor. If ingress file gets saved properly the ingress controller will pick any changes accordingly

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change namespace of existing object. You need to create a new resource in the other namespace and delete the old one.

Comment: Sure Will try to deploy it same name space. Is it as simple as specifying namespace: nginx-ingress in the ingress file?

Comment: @AnilKumarP - yes, you need to specify the new namespace and do `kubectl create -f`